# cant access to props in mounted

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue component like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="page-head">
            <h4 class="mt-2 mb-2"> {{form.name}} </h4>
        </div>
        <form-builder :form="form"></form-builder>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

import FormBuilder from './FormBuilder.vue';

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            form : {}
        }
    },
    components : {
        'form-builder' : FormBuilder
    },
    mounted : function () {
        let formUid = this.$route.params.uid;
        axios.get(`/api/form/uid/${formUid}`).then(res => {
            this.form = res.data;
        });
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

As you can see, this component gets a form instance from database and passes it to another component called `FormBuilder`.
And now In my Form Builder component I have :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3> Test : {{form.id}} </h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : ['form'],
    mounted : function () {
        console.log(this.form.id); // !!! this.form.id is undefined!
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

When I run the code, I can see `form.id` is displayed in h3 tag successfully, but when I console.log `this.form.id` in the mounted section it gives me undefined!!!
Can someone help me with this? why it's undefined?

Answer (score 3):

This is an expected behavior due to the component life cycle, the child component is mounted before the `form.id` is available, the mounted hook is executed once but the template will be re-rendered when  `form.id` is available, to use this prop in your script you should use it with `computed` or `watch` option like :

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h3> Test : {{form.id}} </h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : ['form'],
    watch:{
       form(newVal,oldVal){
            console.log('watch : ',this.form.id)  //if you check the console you'll see
                                                  // watch : undefined
                                                   // watch : "your value" 
        }
    }, 
    mounted : function () {
        console.log(this.form.id); // !!! this.form.id is undefined!
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```